# Avoiding multiple fields for every year

Tags: fields

I have few custom objects with repetitive custom fields. I add few new fields for at the start of each year such as 2015_Target__c, 2015_Actuals__C, 2016_Target__c, 2016_Actuals__C.

How to set this as a one off field instead of repeating for each year.

Thanks you for any help

Comment: Are `Last_Year_Target__c`, `Last_Year_Actuals__c`, `This_Year_Target__c`, and `This_Year_Actuals__c` acceptable options?

Comment: I want keep historical data as well for reporting. so I need a generic fields such as Target__c, Actuals__c. then link into a another custom object with details of year

Comment: Is there a problem with exporting those values at year end? You can find ways to report on historical data without needing to actually have all of it available at one time.

Comment: No, we do not export any data we keep for last 7 years of data - thanks

Comment: You could create a child object to hold the data if none of the other suggestions work. When you start reusing fields simply to increment a label it is time to review the data model

Comment: Create a text area field(long) and put al historic data their and keep the current year data in field `This_Year_Target__c, and This_Year_Actuals__c`. So you need to create only one field.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a picklist field for the `Year__c` (with values 2015,2016 etc). And 2 separate fields `Target__c` and `Actual__c`.

You can turn on history tracking for all the 3 fields to do reporting.  (And also some validation rules to make it conditionally mandatory, if required)

If you feel history tracking report isn't enough and want intense historical reporting, you can look into using the standard salesforce feature of **"[Analytical Snapshot](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm)"**

**EDIT:** Since you said, you have 20 objects on which these fields needs to be used.  You can create `Year__c` picklist field as a [**Global Picklist**](https://sfdcfanboy.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/awesome-global-picklists/) instead and reference this field in all your objects.  This way, if you want to change the year values, you just edit the Global picklist field and not all the Year fields in 20 objects.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I have about 20 fields in one objects which depends on year start date and year end date (01/01/2016 & 31/12/2016). And also this applies for many objects as well

Comment: @JayWeera ; I'm with sfdcFanBoy here and would recommend Analytic Snapshots. It is SFDC OOB "poor man's BI" if you don't want to license Wave or use a third party tool.

Comment: @JayWeera  Yes, if you need 20 fields, you need to create all of them separately, that's how it is Because all of them are user input fields.  You can save something on the picklist Year though, updated my answer about the Global picklist